# how to use pagination in ListView in django using get_paginate methed

Tags: python, sql, django, methods, paginator

class ManageStudentView(ListView):
model = Student
template_name = 'student/manage_student.html'

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs = super(ManageStudentView, 
    self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    kwargs['student'] = User.objects.filter(user_type=STUDENT)
    return kwargs

def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
    self.paginate_by = settings.PAGINATION_NUMBER
    return self.paginate_by
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that import your models and ListView

```
class YourViewNameHere(ListView):
    paginate_by = 2
    model = Your Model name
```

This limits the number of objects per page and adds a paginator and page_obj to the context. To allow your users to navigate between pages, add links to the next and previous page, in your template like this:

```
{% for some in page_obj %}
    {# Each "some" is a Your model object. #}
    {{ some.full_name|upper }}<br>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```